# Отсутствует перевод в подгруппе "рецензии" группы "все действия" в активности профиля

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Вся информация на скриншоте:

[image: reviewed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю для "reviewed" использовать перевод "проверено".

Добавил перевод на [появившуюся в Transifex фразу](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/102311793?key=1f7b6951ed4d9a88db4fff0a98a3d96e).

Нужно подкачать базу при новой сборке.

Comment: Отличный вариант! Обновил базу строк.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky подождем сборки 4321 для проверки

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky можно закрывать.